# why does compiler show [Error] incompatible type for argument 2

Tags: c

Originally, I want to make a program where the user inputs a username and pin. The program checks if both are within the coded structure. If the input is correct, the program displays a certain amount.

But i have ommitted the rest of the code because I always get the error on the isValid.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct accounts{
    char unList[50];
    int pinList;
    float amtList;

}account;


int isValid(char inputUN[], struct accounts);




int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {


    account newAccs[10];
    char unList[][32] = {"franklin", "woods", "phillips", "gomez", "burns", "porter", "griffin", "spencer", "hanson", "johnson"};

    char inputUN[32];
    int index;

    printf("Enter Username: ");
    scanf("%s", &inputUN);
    printf("Enter PIN: ");
    scanf("%d", &inputPin);


    index = isValid(inputUN, newAccs);
    printf("%d", index);

return 0;
}


int isValid(char inputUN[], struct accounts acount){

    int index;

    for(index = 0; index < 32; index++){
        if (strcmp(inputUN, acount.unList) == 0){
            index = index;
        }
    }
return index;
}
```

Note: I do not need the code for my original program. I just want to know why I always get an error: Incompatible type for argument2 of 'isValid'.
Also I have shortened my code so for my purpose only.

Comment: The `for` loop in the `isValid` function makes zero sense. What are you trying to do?? And `scanf("%s", &inputUN);` → `scanf("%s", inputUN);`

Comment: The loop sir is so I could verify if the username input by the user exists in the array `unList`in the structure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`newAccs` is an *array* of those structures, which will decay to a pointer to the first element when passing it to a function.

So, if you want to use a pointer, you'll need your function to accept `account *`. If you want a *single* account element, you'll need to pass one, such as with `newAccs[4]`.

Which one you choose will depend on your intent (it's a little difficult to discern *which* way you want to go based on your current `isValid` function at the moment since it doesn't use any array indexing despite the presence of a `for` loop).

---

By way of example, here's a function (which I *think* is probably what you're after, based on the information provided) that goes through the entire set of accounts and check if the username exists in one of the entries. It will either return the index of that entry or -1 if not found:

```
int findUN (char *userName, account *accountList, int accountSz) {
    int idx;
    for (idx = 0; idx < accountSz; idx++)
        if (strcmp (userName, accountList[idx].unList) == 0)
            return idx;
    return -1;
}
```

Then you call it with something like:

```
int idx = findUN (inputUN, newAccs, sizeof(newAccs) / sizeof(*newAccs));
```

You'll notice I've done *two* things differently there. The first is to accept a *pointer* to an account structure (the pointer to the first of the ten in the array).

The second is to pass the size of that array, basically the size in bytes of the entire array divided by the size in bytes of one element in that array.

That's because the decay of the array into a pointer does not let you later extract the array size. To do that, you need to pass it separately.

Comment: I'm very sorry sir but I'm new to C Programming.
may I know what I should type then instead? May i know the code?

Comment: @Angelo, before a solution can be given, the problem must be understood. You need to make it clearer what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: sir, I think I am trying to access the structure `newAccs` and use it as a parameter for my function `isValid`

Comment: @Angelo, I've added sample code for what I *think* is your most likely case.

Comment: Sir thank you, I have understood quite better now, but may I ask you what you mean when you say _decay to a pointer_ or _decay to a pointer_?

Comment: @Angelo, that's probably worth asking as another question to get more details but, in *most* circumstances when you have an array like `int x[10]`, using `x` in your source code will end up giving you the address of `x[0]`. That's what decaying means.

Answer (score 0):

The method `isValid` expects as single instance of `accounts` as second parameter but you are passing an array to it while calling the method.

So either you need to change the method signature to

```
int isValid(char inputUN[], struct accounts *);
```

or pass a single instance of `accounts` from the array while calling the method as

```
isValid(inputUN, newAccs[someindex]);
```

Comment: But sir I have already used a typedef to define the structure and used the tag `account`